# Dynamic Rectangles in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays

I am still very new to coding so I am just practicing by attempting to make some simple games like Snake. Right now I am trying to make the trail follow the head when an apple is eaten, but I have run into a problem.

I currently have it so that the tail pieces spawn in the right place at the right time, but they do not move. They spawn and become static. My tail pieces are stored in an ArrayList and I can't figure out how to update the coordinate values of the rectangles every tick. How do I alter the coordinate values of EVERY Rectangle each tick?

This is what I have so far. Here is part of my Snake class that spawns the tail pieces and paints them

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> xValues = new ArrayList(1);
public static ArrayList<Integer> yValues = new ArrayList(1);
public static ArrayList<Rectangle> tails = new ArrayList(1);
public static int tail = 1;

public static void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight);

    if(Apple.collision) {
        tails.add(new Rectangle(xValues.get(xValues.size() - tail), 
        yValues.get(yValues.size() - tail), sWidth, sHeight));
        System.out.println(tails.size());
        Apple.collision = false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < tails.size(); i++) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(tails.get(i).x, tails.get(i).y, tails.get(i).width, tails.get(i).height);
    }
}

public static void update() {
    sx += svx;
    sy += svy;

    xValues.add(sx);
    yValues.add(sy);
}
```

What I want to do is every game tick I want to increment the variable 'tail' by 1. So just tail++. I do this in my Apple class when the Snake eats the Apple.

```
    public static void update() {
    if(Snake.sx == ax && Snake.sy == ay) {
        ax = (int) ((20 - 0) * random()) * 20;
        ay = (int) ((20 - 0) * random()) * 20;
        Snake.tail++;

        collision = true;
    }
```

But this the Rectangles aren't dynamic so they don't increment tail each tick.

I know I can find the x value of each rectangle by setting a for loop and have like

```
tail.get(i).getBounds().getX;
```

But I cannot figure out how I can change the coordinate values while the program is running.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To keep the `tails` rectangles updated, you would either have to go through the list every tick and set the coordinates of each tail segment to the coordinates of the one in front of it, or you would have to add a new rectangle and drop the oldest one (like a FIFO queue) every tick.

However, since you're already storing all the past x/y values, the `tails` list contains only redundant information. You could drop it entirely and just read the last `tail` number of x/y values to get each tail coordinate.

```
public static void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillRect(sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight);

    if (Apple.collision) {
//      tail++; // could do this here instead of in Apple.update
        System.out.println(tail);
        Apple.collision = false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tail; i++) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(xValues.get(xValues.size() - 1 - i), yValues.get(yValues.size() - 1 - i), sWidth, sHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that makes so much more sense to me now! I was just guessing and checking but you made it so simple. Thank you very much!